# JXTA 2.7 SEVERE: World Peer Group could not be instantiated.

Tags: java, p2p, jxta

trying to run the example files of JXSE 2.7 // Connecting with OSGI, Edge_Dimitri Sending messages etc, I get this error

```
PSE Membmership Service started.
Oct 23, 2012 8:20:13 AM net.jxta.impl.peergroup.StdPeerGroup initFirst
SEVERE: Failed to make PSE membership credential 'ready for join'
Oct 23, 2012 8:20:13 AM net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory newWorldPeerGroup
SEVERE: World Peer Group could not be instantiated.

net.jxta.exception.PeerGroupException: Failed to login to this group: null. Error=0
at net.jxta.impl.peergroup.StdPeerGroup.initFirst(StdPeerGroup.java:704)
at net.jxta.impl.peergroup.Platform.initFirst(Platform.java:214)
at net.jxta.impl.peergroup.GenericPeerGroup.init(GenericPeerGroup.java:907)
at net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory.newWorldPeerGroup(WorldPeerGroupFactory.java:312)
at net.jxta.peergroup.WorldPeerGroupFactory.<init>(WorldPeerGroupFactory.java:182)
at net.jxta.peergroup.NetPeerGroupFactory.<init>(NetPeerGroupFactory.java:203)
at net.jxta.platform.NetworkManager.startNetwork(NetworkManager.java:408)
at Examples.A_JXTA_Connection_And_Local_Configuration._160_Connecting_With_OSGi.main(_160_Connecting_With_OSGi.java:66)
```

Here is my Java Build path (Using eclipse)

[image: Build Path]

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: [JVerstry](http://stackoverflow.com/users/520957/jverstry) could you spot the error? Thanks!